# When I double click on a jsTree node, it triggers a single click as well. Is there a way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am new to jsTree.  I have a simple tree structure of Apartement complexes with children of the Units inside each complex.   When I double click the root node, its children open up correctly... but it also triggers the click event I have assigned.  Is there any way to prevent the click event, when I double click the node?

I've looked through the jsTree API and haven't found any explanation about this odd behavior.

********* ADDITION INFORMATION  ************************

I discovered that my change did not fix the problem.
Here is the relevant code I am currently using for my jsTree Tree:

```
// jsTree Container Element
<div id="mainPropertyTree"></div>

// This is a subset of the JSON structure being loaded with the "lclData" variable below
[   {id: 'P1',parent: '#',text: 'Lakeshore @ Preston 3700 Preston Road  (P1)',type: 'typeMF',pId: '1',uId: '2'},
    {id: 'P2',parent: '#',text: 'Shorecrest Homes   (P2)',type: 'typeDpx',pId: '2',uId: '4'},
    {id: 'T1',parent: 'U1',text: 'Aristeo Gamino (T1)',type: '',pId: '-1',uId: '-1'},
    {id: 'T3',parent: 'U4',text: 'Damara Sampson (T3)',type: '',pId: '-1',uId: '-1'},
    {id: 'U1',parent: '#',text: '411 Bonham Drive  (U1)',type: 'typeSF',pId: '3',uId: '1'},
    {id: 'U2',parent: 'P1',text: '3700 Preston Rd #1111  (U2)',type: 'typeMF',pId: '1',uId: '2'},
    {id: 'U4',parent: 'P2',text: '3252 Shorecrest Drive  (U4)',type: 'typeDpx',pId: '2',uId: '4'},
    {id: 'U5',parent: '#',text: '2525 South Bend Lane East Side (U5)',type: 'typeSF',pId: '4',uId: '5'},
    {id: 'U6',parent: '#',text: '500 West Broadway  (U6)',type: 'typeSF',pId: '5',uId: '6'},
]
            // This is the code inside the JQuery Ajax Success Event Handler
            // The "lclData" variable contains the JSON structure from above
            $("#mainPropertyTree").jstree({
                core:{ data: lclData,
                       themes: {variant:"large"}
                     },
                plugins: ["wholerow"]
            });                            

            // This is the "Click.jstree" event handler
            // This gets called even if I double click the node
            $("#mainPropertyTree").on("click.jstree", function(e) {
                // Display the database record for the nodes selected (parent, grandparent...etc)
                if (!e.target.id)
                    return;

                var currId = jsTreeTransId(e.target.id).id;  // this just cleans up the node ID
                var node = $(this).jstree().get_node( currId );
                displayCurrentNode(node);
            });
```

I am new with jsTree, so make no presumptions about my knowledge :)

Comment: some code would help

Comment: mayha... you're right, I should have left some code, sorry about that.  As it turns out I was using the "Changed.jstree" event, not the "Click". If I had included code, I would have noticed that before posting my question. Embarrassingly stupid of me. 

After changing it to the "Click" event, all is good.